# Having a hard time with yaml

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I want to make hierarchical data with yaml, unfortunately, I'm not much used to this format, but I'd love to use it because it's human friendly.

Here is my yaml:

```
items:
    list1:
        itemA:
            item property a
        itemB:
    list2:
        itemC:
        itemD:
```

I'm using yaml-cpp and when I do `doc["items"]["list1"]["itemA"]`, I end up with exception TypedKeyNotFound, and I don't think I understand well how yaml is supposed to be used, I do

```
doc["items"]["list1"]["itemA"].Type()
```

but I still have this exception.

Comment: nice reputation, haha, I won't upvote you just to keep it like that :P

Comment: Can you post a complete (small) example that demonstrates this? In particular, show how you're loading the YAML. Also, make sure you're using spaces, not tabs, for indentation in the YAML file.

Comment: Is it valid YAML? I can't work out what it's meant to represent.

Comment: @David, it is valid YAML - what looks wrong? (remember that null nodes are allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to better understand how yaml works, and also how it can be parsed. I don't want to get data like this  a["fdfds"]["frwrew"]["vbxvxc"], because I don't want to require to know the key before parsing. I managed to make a code which shows the structure of a document using mostly maps and sequences, here it is.

```
int spaces = 0; // define it in global scope, since unroll is a recursive function.
void unroll(const YAML::Node & node)
{
switch(node.Type())
{
    case YAML::NodeType::Map:       
    {
        for(auto it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++ it)
        {
            string s; it.first() >> s;
            indent();
            cout << s << "\n";
            const YAML::Node & dada = it.second();
            spaces ++;
            unroll(dada);
            spaces--;
            cout << "\n";
        }
        break;
    }

    case YAML::NodeType::Scalar:
    {
        indent();
        string s; node >> s;
        cout << "found scalar " << s << "\n";
        break;
    }
    case YAML::NodeType::Null:
    {
        indent();
        cout << "null";
        break;
    }
    case YAML::NodeType::Sequence:
    {
        //cout << "sequence";
        for(auto it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++ it)
        {
            string s; *it >> s;
            indent();
            cout << s << "\n";
        }
        break;
    }
    default: cout << "error: undefined";    break;
}
}
```